# Unable to add kotlinx-coroutines-reactor to commonMain in KMM

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

So I'm trying to use `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` to try out the Flux pattern in my KMM project.

I've tried versions `1.6.4` and `1.6.3-native-mt` but can only use flows, for some reason Flux isn't available. I can't import it, and when I try and manually import it, it says unresolved reference.

It looks like the package is pure kotlin, so I'm not sure why it can't be imported. If I put the dependencies under `androidMain` I can use it, but not under `commonMain` where I'd like to keep things common.

I want to place it under common to have my list of side effects be shared between platforms.

Answer (score 1):

[Project reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core) is **not** compatible with android or any other mobile platform, it is a java/jvm project.

Therefore, the compatibility layer provided between Project Reactor and Kotlin coroutines is also only available in Kotlin JVM based projects. If you take a look at the [kotlinx-coroutine-reactor build file](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactor/build.gradle.kts) you will see that it only defines configuration for jvm target.

I have not very much experience with multiplatform mobile projects, but I'd say that Kotlin coroutine Flow API is the way to deal with datastream. Now, with a little search, maybe you can find a pure Kotlin multiplatform Rx Kotlin library to replace Reactor, if you really need to.